# Boundary Fill pixel to pixel using recursive not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm still new to javascript, and I'm still kinda confused, how to make a boundary fill with recursive. because the code still didn't work. I think there is something that went wrong when I declared the boundary color. I'm actually not really sure about how to declare it. I don't know why the result becomes a line. I didn't find any solutions on the internet. could you please help me? what am I supposed to do?

here's the code:

```js
var canvas= document.querySelector('canvas'); 
    canvas.width= "1030";
    canvas.height= "430";
    const c = canvas.getContext('2d');

    window.onload=function() {covercanvas()};

    function covercanvas()
    {
        c.fillStyle="#f5f7cd";
        c.fillRect(0, 0, 1030, 430);
    }

    function linemaker()
    {
        // When true, moving the mouse draws on the canvas
        let isDrawing = false;
        let x = 0;
        let y = 0;

        // event.offsetX, event.offsetY gives the (x,y) offset from the edge of the canvas.

        // Add the event listeners for mousedown, mousemove, and mouseup
        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
            x = e.offsetX;
            y = e.offsetY;
            isDrawing = true;
        });

        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
            if (isDrawing === true) {
                drawLine(c, x, y, e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
                x = e.offsetX;
                y = e.offsetY;
            }
        });

        window.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
            if (isDrawing === true) {
                drawLine(c, x, y, e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
                x = 0;
                y = 0;
                isDrawing = false;
            }
        });
        

        function drawLine(c, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
            c.beginPath();
            c.strokeStyle = 'black';
            c.lineWidth = 1;
            c.moveTo(x1, y1);
            c.lineTo(x2, y2);
            c.stroke();
            c.closePath();
        }
    }

    function putpixel(c, x, y, fillcolor)
    {
        c.fillStyle = "#" + fillcolor;
        c.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
    }

    function hexAToRGBA(h) {
      let r = 0, g = 0, b = 0, a = 1;

      if (h.length == 4) {
        r = "0x" + h[1] + h[1];
        g = "0x" + h[2] + h[2];
        b = "0x" + h[3] + h[3];
        a = "0x" + h[4] + h[4];

      } else if (h.length == 8) {
        r = "0x" + h[1] + h[2];
        g = "0x" + h[3] + h[4];
        b = "0x" + h[5] + h[6];
        a = "0x" + h[7] + h[8];
      }
      a = +(a / 255).toFixed(3);
      

      return "rgba(" + +r + "," + +g + "," + +b + "," + +a + ")";
    }

    function boundaryrecursive()
    {
        let x=0;
        let y=0;
        
        canvas.addEventListener('click', e => {
            x = e.offsetX;
            y = e.offsetY;
            
            var fillcolor = document.getElementById("colorinput").value;
            var fill = hexAToRGBA(fillcolor);
            var boundarycolor = document.getElementById("blackboundary");
            var bound_color = hexAToRGBA(window.getComputedStyle(boundarycolor, null).getPropertyValue("background"));
            //alert(bound_color);
            boundary(c, x, y, fill, bound_color, fillcolor);
        });
    }

    function boundary(c, x, y, fill, bound_color, fillcolor)
    {
        var currentpixel = c.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
        var currentpix = hexAToRGBA(currentpixel);
        if (currentpix != fill && currentpix != bound_color)
        {
            putpixel(c, x, y, fillcolor);
            boundary(c, x+1, y, fill, bound_color, fillcolor);
            boundary(c, x-1, y, fill, bound_color, fillcolor);
            boundary(c, x, y+1, fill, bound_color, fillcolor);
            boundary(c, x, y-1, fill, bound_color, fillcolor);
        }
    }
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid }
#blackboundary
{
background-color: black;
position: absolute;
top:1%;
left:1%;
display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <button class="button" onclick="linemaker()">Make a line</button>
<div id="blackboundary">
  <button class="boundarybutton" onclick="boundaryrecursive()">Boundary fill</button>
</div>
    <p id="colortext"> Input your Hex+A value here: </p>
    <input type="text" id="colorinput"></input>
```

Comment: you say `var boundarycolor = document.getElementById("blackboundary");` but there's nothing with `id="blackboundary"` in your code so `boundarycolor` is not what you think it is

Comment: Hello Dwaramji. For starters, it would be useful if you had a look at console errors of your code. Run it in a browser, open the Dev Tools ([Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools)) and for example look at the error created by `document.getElementById("blackboundary")`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I'm so sorry, I forgot. thankyou so much.

Comment: Hello Barthy. thank you so much for the advice @Barthy